# how to checked item of listbox with condition

Tags: c#

i have a page for edit information. i have a cheboxlist that i fill it from `TBLGroupCustomers` this way:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
                            ConnectionStrings["ZagmaDBConnectionString2"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select * from TBLGroupCustomers";
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            ListItem item = new ListItem();
                            item.Text = sdr["GName"].ToString();
                            item.Value = sdr["GName"].ToString();
                            chkList.Items.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
```

now i want checked the list from `TBLG_Groups` my code:

```
 SqlCommand sqlCmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT GName from TBLG_Groups WHERE CEmail = @cemail", connection);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

            string em1 = Request.QueryString["cemail"];
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cemail", em1 );
            sqlDa.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //how to do here?

            }
            connection.Close();
```

how to do for get list of `gnames` that `cemails` is `em1`

Comment: try loop trough `cheboxlist` and, in that loop when condition is satisfied (for example, item is checked) , use `dr.Rows.Select("YourFieldName = 'CheckBoxListItemValue'")`

Comment: i don't understand your answer please explain it in code

Comment: i think you realize,  i wrote a comment, not an answer... comment telling you in which direction you have to go finding answer...